# Conditional if/then queries in CSS

Tags: css, conditional-statements

How do I write conditional statements for CSS?

I've seen all types of information from

```
if {...]
@when
```

as well as `@media`.

I want to write code for the social (tertiary) buttons to move towards the middle of the page when my site is viewed on smaller screen. I currently have two rows of menu buttons for smaller screens, making the social buttons disappear. I've been reading on various types of syntax but am not sure how to form this.

Thanks

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and update your question to be about the *specific* problem you're having with it.

Comment: .tertiary-menu {
    height: 40px;
     /* Add this when rows are triggered'; */
    if( @boldgrid_framework_menu  ){
        background: black;
       }
}

Comment: anybody have a suggestion on fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no if else in CSS. There is if you are using Blogger. If I want to display something in a mobile screen, I would add this block of code to my css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width : 1600px) {
.tertiary-menu {
display:none;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 479px) {
.tertiary-menu {
display:block;
}
}
```

> This means that a screen smaller than 479px. You can add `and (min-width: <size>px;)` to set a min and max range on when the element should show up.

If you want to click on something to show the menu, I'm afraid you have to use Javascript for that. There are ways to display menus using CSS, if you could check the search bar here: eatingisliving.com. It uses CSS to expand the search bar. Some items also disappears when the screen is resize. To use CSS to show other elements, you can use something like `.secondary-menu:hover ~ .tertiary-menu { }` or `.secondary-menu:focus ~ .tertiary-menu { }` but it's limited to sibling or child elements only. Only the parent element or a sibling before the target element can trigger it.

If you could provide your codes and more details. I can help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks you Vinz.  I tried .secondary-menu:focus ~ .tertiary-menu {background-color: yellow; }  for example and it doesn't trigger the change.

Comment: For it to work they have to be right next to each other:
`<div class='secondary-menu'></div><div class='tertiary-menu'></div>`.
Or if it's inside `<div class='secondary-menu'><div class='tertiary-menu'></div></div>`, you can do `.secondary-menu:focus > .tertiary-menu`.

Comment: If your 3rd button is already showing on bigger screen and you want to move it to the middle, you can use something like `@media only screen and (max-width:479px) { .tertiary-menu { position:absolute; top:x%; left:x%; } }`. It's tricky sometimes to reposition though.

Comment: thank you so much Vinz, that was my best route.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Vinz, I have another question that you may be able to help me with.  What should I use (plugin or otherwise) to make all my images and text consistently fit on all devices?  Obviously the media querries are helping a ton but still some of my pages are not consistent with the format I've created with text and image.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you set the @media, it should fit on different devices properly. Of course you have to set from the smallest and largest possible (e.g. less than 479px, 480px to 768px, 769px to 985px, 986px or more). If an element doesn't show properly in a screen size range, then you have to adjust the properties there. You could add as many as you want, you can set one for just 1 specific element (e.g. max-width: 800px and another one 801px to 1000px --- any element in this group would display as how you set it with screen size less than 800px).

Comment: If you use this a lot, you can use % for element sizes to make things a bit easier. If you stick to px, the alignments would get messy. If the elements get too tight (e.g. screen size 900px --- 2 buttons could share a row you could set 50% for each button), change the width of the element to 100% to push the other button to the next line, this works using the `float` property.

Comment: Where would I add the float property?  In the media query?

Comment: If they share the same row then they should float. If both have width:100% then they should be float:none. E.g. `@media only screen and (max-width:1600px) { .element1 { float:left; width:50%; } .element2 { float:left; width:50%; } } @media only screen and (max-width:479px) { .element1 { float:none; width:100%; } .element2 { float:none; width:100%; } }`